AMPscript in Location Entry push keeps runs when opening the app
We created a location entry message that has an AMPscript code that basically updates a field in a Data Extension by adding 1 to the value of that field. We implemented this solution to count push notifications sent to the contact during the day, as the Mobile Push SendLog does not consider the Location messages.
The problem is that, when I am in a geofence, I receive the message and the field is updated, and if I click the message (which opens the app) the field is updated again, and If I keep opening and closing the app, the field will be updated every time I open the app.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Please open a support case.

I already did. They do not help with "custom solutions"
